# delete one row in the middle and how to refresh the table id(auto increment) in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

For example:

```
Row Name
1   John
2   May
3   Marry
4   Tom
5   Peter
```

Suppose I delete row 2 and row 3, is it possible to update Tom and Peter to row id 2 and 3 respectively and the next insert row to be row id 4?

Comment: You can try using a trigger for that kind o situation

Comment: trigger is a database code that will be automatically executed according to some database events. Check here for more details, I'm supposing you're using MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 2):

yes, but you need to recreate Row:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` DROP `Row`;
ALTER TABLE `users` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `Row` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, because think of the problems that this could create. Imagine if you are managing a store inventory and each item has an internal barcode, based on an ID in a database table. You decide never to stock one item again and take it out of the database, and then every ID for every item with an ID greater than the removed item gets decremented by 1... all those barcodes on all those items become useless.

ID numbers in databases aren't generally meant to be used or referenced by people. They are meant to be a static index of a certain item in a database which allows the computer to pull up a given record quickly and reliably. When creating your ID field of your table, make sure you make the datatype large enough to account for these lost IDs when they do occur.

Comment: Well, it is possible, whether it should be done is a different question. Nice explanation though.

Comment: I think that what he wants is to order the values, so there is no problem since he creates a new column specifically to this situation

Comment: @Nikoloff Yes, fair point, but I assumed he was looking for a setting whereby the auto-increment would automatically do that for him, not the answer given below by Elen which would of course work.

Comment: @Gerep The values will always be ordered because deleted ids are not re-used. It isn't "pretty" to have the missing numbers but the order remains.

Comment: @user1068266 Yeah..I know that, you are 100% right but I don't think that these numbers are primary key, they are a just a int column

Comment: @Gerep Ah didn't think of that, just assumed they would be the PK. Fair enough then.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion. I don't say this is the best solution. Just consider.

You execute your delete query.

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE Row IN (2,3);
```

Once deleted you make a select query request with PHP and get the data set to an array.

```
SELECT Row, Name from table_name ORDER BY Row ASC;
```

Then make a UPDATE execution using a loop.

```
$index = 1;
foreach($dataset as $item)
{
// Your update query
$sql = "UPDATE table_name SET Row=$index where Name='" . $item['Name'] . "'";
$index++;
}
```

Before you insert next query you have to get the max value of Row and set +1 value as the Row of the insert query.
This is just an idea. Not the complete code.